# How i can retrive data after submitting form from asp site via curl php

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I have to retrive data from http://delhipolice.serverpeople.com/firweb/Index.aspx?SubMenuId=2 after submitting form via curl but i am unable to do so. Can Any one help me out.

```
$kv[]='ctl00$txtRegNo=565';
$kv[]='ctl00$ddlDistrict=170';
$kv[]='ctl00$ddlYear=2013';
$query_string = join("&", $kv);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry mate, you're going to have to provide more details. What mechanism are you currently using to submit the form? You have tagged your question with php and asp.net - which are you using? What data are you trying to collect? You get the picture? (no, not that last one)

Comment: What is your question, what about the code you show doesn't work?

Comment: my code works but don't give desired output. That's why I am here

Comment: What is the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for result set after form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get correct output, because it asp site. By submitting form you should also add additional post params like __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTTARGET

Comment: try to this one http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html